# Pings from my network suddenly started to fail, despite having a working internet connection

Tags: networking, ping

My connection has been dropping out fairly regularly so I wrote a scheduled task yesterday to ping google's DNS server every 5 minutes and record the result, so I have a note of when it's happening in case we need to talk to the ISP about it. However, after a few hours, every ping started failing.

What could be causing this, and is it likely to be something out of my control e.g. a fault on the ISP's end?

Some details:

- All computers on the network have this problem now
- I can ping within the network, just not anything outside it
- I've tried restarting/reconnecting the computers and the router to no effect

Comment: Are other connections also failing from inside to outside? Can you resolve DNS using Google's dns `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: You must talk with ISP. I've seen exactly same problem & ISP solved that. Try to use `tracert` to trace any IP address (e.g. Google.com) and find the faulty hop.

Comment: Is there a specific error that is occuring?

Comment: It's fixed itself now. I suppose it must have been the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is stable and works within you network 100% when the issue occurs, ISP seems the way to go, however to rule out further if possible:

- Have a wireshark capture running overnight to see what is catched when ping fails.
- Try pinging a different IP.